# Enable H2 Debug Console for Ignite.Net

Tags: ignite

I am having trouble figuring out how to configure the H2 Debug Console for Ignite.Net.  The following article describes using the H2 Debug Console:

https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/sql-queries#using-h2-debug-console

However, I am not sure how to incorporate into my .Net solution so that I can access it.  Do you have any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following line anywhere before `Ignition.Start()`:

`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("IGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE", "true")`

This will open H2 debug console in browser on Ignite startup. You may need to refresh the window to see newly created caches.

Keep in mind that this console is not for viewing cache contents, since not all data is visible there. It is for trying out SQL queries, and you have to have query entities configured accordingly.